# what does .carousel('dispose') actually do?

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

what does .carousel('dispose') actually do?
When I call this function slider just stops moving slides. It still is in the screen and i can use next/prev to move slides. 
Code link:
https://codepen.io/smith1919/pen/wvvVrMR
Note: in code i have created destroy button that calls

```
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel('dispose');
```

Comment: From docs, It [`Destroys an element’s carousel.`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#carouseldispose)

Comment: Yes, but everything works in the carouses which is contradictory!

Comment: Might be worth asking / opening an [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues). What's for sure is that the documentation is not very clear about what it does (if anything).